# Installing Material UI in React Create App TS Project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, node-modules

I am creating a React project with `npx create-react-app ./ --template typescript`. It is all fine until here, with no errors.

After that, I want to install Material UI so I use `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`, but I get vulnerabilities.

I've been trying to fix this but can't find a solution; if I do `npm audit fix --force` or `npm audit fix` I only get more vulnerabilities instead of less.

If someone can help me it would be great.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Don't worry about those you have installed miu in you project just ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple answer, it is pretty much unfixable, but it is not essential to fix those `vulnerabilities`.

And that you have installed all target `dependencies`, and can run the project with no related errors.

---

First, the problem comes from `create-react-app` (namely `react-scripts`); instead of `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`.

`create-react-app` is a framework that helps you set up a web application in a few clicks, but it was deprecated around 3 years ago (source: [create-react-app Github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)).

Often `vulnerabilities` are fixed in later versions, however, as `create-react-app` is no longer maintained, it relies on old versions that consist of such `vulnerabilities`, and it might cause problems if you upgrade the `dependencies`.

And usually checking via `npm audit`, it would recommend you use `npm audit fix`, which means minor updates (e.g. `1.0.x` to `1.1.x`) could fix the problem.

But in the above case, you are suggested to use `npm audit fix --force`, which means only major updates (e.g. `1.x.x` to `2.x.x`) could fix the problem (but it usually would break the application).

---

However, `vulnerabilities` are not **unforgivable** - you can still run the project; unless you are working on projects that require serious security measures - the `create-react-app` team even suggested [ignoring those `vulnerabilities` warning](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174) (thanks for @Phil's information).

And if you are greatly concerned about the `vulnerabilities`, a good practice is to convert your project to `Vite` or `Next.js`
(as recommended by [`React`](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project)).

Comment: Another interesting point is, that `create-react-app` does not support `Typescript` with version `5.x` ([source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080)); so you might encounter another problem with your setup.